# Subsetting time based data in R on hourly basis

Tags: r, subset

i have hour based data set, i.e some rows of data for hour1 and so on. I dont know the number of rows of data for each hour and i want to create a new data set with only first entry of each hour. 
 for a data set like this,

```
hour    data
1   33
1   34
1   36
2   38
2   40
3   41
3   42
```

i want to extract only first reading of hour 1 and then first of hour 2 and so on. Then i want to subtract consecutive readings. like, 38-33 and 41-38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr) # df1 is your data frame
df1 %>%
group_by(hour) %>%
summarise(first=first(data))%>%
mutate(first_diff=lead(first,1)-first)
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  hour first first_diff
1    1    33          5
2    2    38          3
3    3    41         NA
```

OR,

```
library(dplyr) # df1 is your data frame
df1 %>%
group_by(hour) %>%
summarise(first=first(data))%>%
mutate(first_diff=lag(first,1)-first)
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  hour first first_diff
1    1    33         NA
2    2    38         -5
3    3    41         -3
```